# Excel macro doesn't work after reset profile windows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with an Excel macro who doesn't work with a User1 after to have reset the profile Windows of User1. Before the reset profile, it worked.
The line in error is `Application.Workbooks("Filename without extension").Activate.`

I done a lot of test :

- apparently file's right of User1 to access on Filename are good
- a User2 connect on the User1's PC and test the Excel Macro = OK
- a User1 connect on the User2's PC and test the Excel Macro = KO
- a User2 connect on the User2's PC and test the Excel Macro = OK

It's probably a permission problem because of the reset profile ? Or may be is there cache file excel to delete ?

Thanks.

Comment: Always add the extension to the filename, that way it will work regardless of the pesky windows setting that hides extensions of known filetypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that your statement works any time - AFAIK `workbooks.Activate` needs the name with extension in any case (else an runtime error 9 *"Subscript out of range"* occurs). Only exception is when you deal with a new workbook that was not saved yet (eg `workbooks("book1").activate`).

While it is not possible to have 2 workbooks with the same name (but from different folder) open, it is possible to have 2 workbooks with the same name but different extension open at the same time. Excel couldn't distinguish them when it was possible to give the name without extension.

If the filename (with extension) is okay and the activate fails, first check if the file is open at all or if the open already failed.